# Java printing string with fixed width

Tags: java, string, fixed-width

I have to write a code in Java that will take a String and put a certain number of characters on each line (the fixed width). I will also have to put extra spaces in to fill in any extra spots, like if four words only equal 23 characters and the line calls for 25, so I'd need to input two extra spaces. 
This is for a beginning class, so it just needs to be as basic as possible. So far, what I have is:

```
public static void print (String[] theWords, int width) {

  int start = 0, end = 0, lineCounter = 0;
  int[] gaps;
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: what if string exceeds 25 characters  ?

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html to insert characters into a string.

Answer (score 16):

As you have not written what you have done so far, neither how the expected input looks like and what output do you expect. The answer will be weak as well

At least one simple example. For more information about the format string have a look into the related [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

```
System.out.printf("%-25s : %25s%n", "left justified", "right justified");
System.out.printf("%25s : %-25s%n", "right justified", "left justified");
// if you want to get a String
String s1 = String.format("%-25s : %25s%n", "left justified", "right justified");
String s2 = String.format("%25s : %-25s%n", "right justified", "left justified");
```